# Can you have 4 players simultaneously in a Spec Ops survival lobby?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Is it possible to have 4 online players in the same game of Spec Ops (survival mode)?

So far I've only been in teams of 2 but I don't know if that's just a coincidence.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 3-Survival Mode is only 2 player. You didn't just by chance get two player matches that is indeed the limit because it is spec-ops.

Answer (score 5):

You can not have more than 2 players, because that's the limit.

Answer (score 2):

No, sadly, it is only for 2 people.